# QML pieMenu on draggable object

Tags: qt, qml

I've got a draggable object that is created by a Javascript, which is working fine. But when I create a [PieMenu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-extras-piemenu.html#details) inside it, the object isn't created/visible in the Javascript context:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQml.Models 2.2


Rectangle {
        id: rev
        width: 100
        height: 80
        color: "transparent"
        antialiasing: false
        Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active

        MouseArea {
                  id: dragArea
                  width: parent.width
                  height: parent.height + 10 // easier to get
                  anchors.centerIn: parent
                  drag.target: parent
                  drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis
                  onClicked: pieMenu.popup(mouseX, mouseY), console.log("clicked")
                }

        PieMenu {
            id: pieMenu

            MenuItem {
                text: "Add vertical bar"
                onTriggered: print("Action 2")
            }   
        }



        Gauge {
            id: revgauge
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            orientation : Qt.Horizontal
            minorTickmarkCount: 4
            tickmarkStepSize : 5000
            minimumValue: 0
            maximumValue: 10000
            Behavior on value {
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 5
                }
            }
            Text {                    
                font.pixelSize: (parent.height / 3)
                anchors.top : parent.top
                font.bold: true
                font.family: "Eurostile"
                color: "white"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
              style: GaugeStyle {
                valueBar: Rectangle {
                   implicitWidth:  rev.height /3
                    color: Qt.rgba(revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 1)
                }
            }
      }
}
```

Can [Mousearea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) handle dragging and a `PieMenu` at once? If not how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Consider QML `PieMenu` [boundingItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-extras-piemenu.html#boundingItem-prop). It addresses an exact issue with `MouseArea` you presented.